# Why does posexplode fail with "AnalysisException: The number of aliases supplied in the AS clause does not match the number of columns..."?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is my dataframe:

```
+------------------------------------------
|value   
+------------------------------------------
|[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 7.0000000000000036, 0.0]
|[2.0000000000000036, 0.0, 2.9999999999999996, 4.0000000000000036, 5.000000000000002]
|[4.000000000000006, 0.0, 0.0, 6.000000000000006, 7.000000000000004]  
+------------------------------------------
```

When I use:

```
dataFrame.withColumn("item_id", posexplode(dataFrame.col("value")))
```

I got this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: The number of aliases supplied in the AS clause does not match the number of columns output by the UDTF expected 2 aliases but got item_id ;
```

So, how to use posexplode to "Creates a new row for each element with position in the given array or map column."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `posexplode` with the `select` as below

```
dataframe.select($"value", posexplode($"value")).show(false)
```

Which returns two new columns as `pos` and `col`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! But why $"value" can represent 2 aliased?

Comment: The answer uses `select` (not `withColumn`).

Answer (score 13):

Things are clear if you'd use `explode` in `.withColumn()`.

In contrast, before low-prioritized [Spark-20174](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20174) gets accepted and implemented, the use of `posexplode` along with `withColumn` isn't straight forward. You may want to use a workaround based on `selectExpr` as shown below.

```scala
val df = Seq(
  ("a", Seq(1,2,3)),
  ("b", Seq(11,22))).toDF("n", "s")
df.show()

+---+---------+
|  n|        s|
+---+---------+
|  a|[1, 2, 3]|
|  b| [11, 22]|
+---+---------+
```

```scala
df.selectExpr("*", "posexplode(s) as (p,c)").drop("s").show()

+---+---+---+
|  n|  p|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  0|  1|
|  a|  1|  2|
|  a|  2|  3|
|  b|  0| 11|
|  b|  1| 22|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 3):

`posexplode` will create two new columns, one with the value and one with the index. You can use:

```
dataFrame.select(posexplode($"value") as Seq("pos", "val"))
```

This will give you a dataframe containing the indices and values.

---

However, if you only want the actual value it's better to use `explode`:

```
dataFrame.withColumn("val", explode($"value"))
```

Answer (score 1):

posexplode expects 2 reference names to represent the index its creating and actual value that its extracting from your array in each row.

What you can do is use 'Lateral View' after registering your table or view (differ with spark version you are using) like:

```
select ind, val from table_name LATERAL VIEW posexplode(values) exploded_values as ind, val
```

I haven't tried this as I am at workplace but you can definitely try this out.